# Why can't I diagonalize the antiferromagnetic Heisenberg Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, spin-models, ground-state

So I started with the antiferromagnetic Heisenberg Hamiltonian with $J =-1 $: $H = -(-1) \sum_{NN}\sigma_i\cdot\sigma_j$.
I wrote the Pauli-matrices as their matrix-representation and got for eg. the first NN-interaction: $\sigma_x\otimes \sigma_x \otimes \mathbb{1}\otimes \mathbb{1} + \sigma_y\otimes \sigma_y \otimes \mathbb{1}\otimes \mathbb{1} + \sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z \otimes \mathbb{1}\otimes \mathbb{1}$ (but as a 16x16 matrix now. I wont write it here it is just too big).
Then I diagonalized the matrix or calculated its eigenvalues, latter I dit with numpy .

For the ferromagnetic case($J=1$) I get the correct groundstate but for the antiferromagnetic case($J=-1$) I get as the minimal eigenvalue -8.

Comment: You have to show your calculations, since otherwise it is impossible to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I think you're taking a square lattice with periodic boundary conditions. Could you show your calculation?

Comment: Yes I do. It's a bit difficult because it's a16x16 matrix. But I can try to. In principle I write the Pauli-matrices in the Hamiltonian and for each point I take the respective tensor product. So I end up with a 16x16 matrix which I diagonalize to get the Groundstate.

Comment: Why do you think the minimal eigenvalue is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mistake. The ground state energy *is* -8.

```
S={[0 1;1 0],[0 i;-i 0],[1 0;0 -1]};
kk=@(a,b,c,d)(kron(kron(a,b),kron(c,d))); 
H=0; 
for p=1:3 
  s=S{p};e=eye(2);  
  H=H+kk(s,s,e,e)+kk(e,s,s,e)+kk(e,e,s,s)+kk(s,e,e,s); 
end; 
eig(H)
```

returns (in matlab!)

```
-8.0000
-4.0000
-4.0000
-4.0000
-0.0000
-0.0000
      0
      0 
 0.0000
 0.0000
 0.0000
 4.0000
 4.0000
 4.0000
 4.0000
 4.0000
```

I'd say this can be derived by hand, since the ground state is a spin singlet, and the singlet space is spanned by two basis states (singlets in two different pairings), and the Hamiltonian acts by swapping them - so there should be an easy way to see this result.  I might add a discussion later.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I got the same values. But I read in some lecture notes that the ground state is around -6 for this lattices, which really confuses me

Comment: @Schroedinger101 Open boundaries: -6.4641

Comment: Ahh thats why, thank you! There was my mistake. Sorry for the questition.